# Testing a web application's Facebook integration with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cucumber, capybara

I'd like to use Cucumber with Capybara to test my Rails application's Facebook registration procedure by executing the following scenario:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Connect account
  When I go to the home page
  And I press "Connect your Facebook account"
  And I fill in "test@address" for "Email"
  And I fill in "test" for "Password"
  And I press "Login"
  And I press "Allow"
  Then I should be on the dashboard page
```

How do folks approach the problem of integration testing browser-based Facebook integration? A web search turns up only a couple of blog posts that predate the graph API, and they only seem to discuss implementing a precondition that sets up an environment representing a user already logged in to Facebook.

Some specific issues to address:

How does one simulate clicking the `<fb:login-button>` element? The best thing I've come up with (but have yet to test) is to manually fire a click event on the element.

Once the Facebook dialog comes up, does Capybara have access to it? How? This seems required in order to enter the email address and password of a test Facebook account and to install the Facebook app for the test account.

For that matter, how does one manage test accounts? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ indicates that test users can be created and deleted with the Graph API, but the API doesn't look to to provide access to an email address or password for a test account, which seems to make them useless for testing this particular flow.

I'm sure I'm overlooking other important issues as well. I sure am curious how other folks have attacked this problem!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: I never got any further with the original approach, but mocking the external service is probably the smart way to go anyway (see the OmniAuth reference in the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get this working in rspec acceptance specs with the following code:

https://gist.github.com/1084767

This uses mogli to create and destroy test users and capybara to orchestrate the browser test. I believe you could get it working with Cucumber by removing the shared_context block and using Cucumber before/after hooks, like:

```
Before '@fb_test_user' do
  @fb_user = create_test_user(installed: false)
end

After '@fb_test_user' do
  @fb_user.destroy
end

World(FacebookIntegrationHelpers)
```

Comment: where is AppConfig.facebook.access_token come from?

Comment: that's an application specific configuration mechanism. it just returns the access token facebook provides when you set up an application on their site.

Answer (score 13):

i'm currently using the omniauth gem to handle this type of authentication. FBML is deprecated, so I suggest moving to the JS SDK for client side FB interaction. Anyways, if you're using omniauth, you can stub out the response relatively easily by specifying some Before tags in your env folder like so:

## Config Success case:

```
Before('@omniauth_test_success') do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
    "provider"  => "facebook",
    "uid"       => '12345',
    "user_info" => {
      "email" => "email@email.com",
      "first_name" => "John",
      "last_name"  => "Doe",
      "name"       => "John Doe"
      # any other attributes you want to stub out for testing
    }
  }
end
```

## Config Failure Case

```
Before('@omniauth_test_failure') do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  [:default, :facebook, :twitter].each do |service|
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[service] = :invalid_credentials
    # or whatever status code you want to stub
  end
end
```

## Cukes Feature

```
Scenario: A user unsuccessfully signs in with their email/password
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I follow "Login"
    And I "unsuccessfully" sign in with email and pass
    Then I should see "Failed."

@omniauth_test_success
  Scenario: A user successfully signs in with Facebook
    Given I am on the homepage
    And I follow "Login"
    When I follow "facebook"
    Then I should see "Login successful."

@omniauth_test_failure
  Scenario: A user unsuccessfully signs in with Facebook
    Given I am on the homepage
    And I follow "Login"
    When I follow "facebook"
    Then I should see "Failed."
```

Comment: Point well taken regarding the JS SDK. I've been meaning to look into OmniAuth. That said, what exactly are you testing in  your success and failure scenarios? Are you verifying some of your application code that's being executed as a result of the follow facebook step? Otherwise it seems like you're not testing anything other than OmniAuth's implementation of its mock service ;) Perhaps the answer to that question will become clear to me when I dig into that library.

Comment: Can you say where (what files) to include the first two segments of code? I know the third goes in a .feature file.