# Testing facebook login with rails cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cucumber, omniauth, facebook-login

I have set up Facebook login on my site following [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw) and am using cucumber and capybara. I have tried following other SO posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331045/testing-a-web-applications-facebook-integration-with-cucumber) that explain how to set up a fake login account. If I use this directly, I get:

```
When I follow "sign_in"                                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
      No route matches [GET] "/oauth/authorize" (ActionController::RoutingError)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:57:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/facebook_signin.feature:9:in `When I follow "sign_in"'
```

If I add `get "/oauth/authorize"` to my routes, I get:

```
When I follow "sign_in"                                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
      uninitialized constant OauthController (ActionController::RoutingError)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:57:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/facebook_signin.feature:9:in `When I follow "sign_in"'
```

I don't know what is going on and why it is complaining. If I change my Gemfile from `gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'` to just `gem 'omniauth-facebook'` I get virtually the same errors above except instead of:

`/oauth/authorize`, I get `/dialog/oauth` and instead of `uninitialized constant OauthController`, I get `uninitialized constant DialogController`

Has anyone recently successfully set up cucumber testing for login with Facebook?

When I am on localhost:3000 and navigate to localhost:3000/auth/facebook everything works and I am using a sessionsController so I don't understand why in testing, it is trying to use these oauthControllers or DialogueControllers.

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the same issue or a very similar issue:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches [GET] "/dialog/oauth"
```

I had taken the working specs which properly set up mock responses from another project and was pretty surprised to suddenly get this error.

After much pain and suffering I had a major facepalm moment when I realized i had forgot to set OmniAuth to use test mode:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

This will cause OmniAuth to short circuit so that you can set the auth responses by:

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
  :provider => 'facebook',
  :uid => '123545'
  # etc.
})
```

I think the error is due to OmniAuth trying to be helpful by using the `:developer` strategy in the test environment so that you don't get banned by the auth provider.

See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Javascript in this tests? As the tutorial mentions the facebook.js.coffee?

```
describe 'When I follow "sign in"', js: true do
```

Another possibility is that you included the gem only in the `development` block of the Gemfile

```
group :development do
  gem 'omniauth-facebook'
end
```

BTW: you shouldn't be testing against "real" external endpoints. Take a look at [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) for this kind of tests to mock the Facebook response

Comment: I have upvoted this, as it solved my problem. However, I note that I am executing the test using the live api, in order that I can record it with the vcr gem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put @omniauth_test_success before the feature and not the step definition. Additionally, I had to fix some routing issues. Will post full report later this week.